# How to find value of respective key using Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Dictionary
         string[,]  Words = new string [,]

```
      /*****Word and Meaning****/

     {{"Absolute","Complete"},                         
     {"Custom","Tradition"},                      
     {"Design","Plan"},                     
     {"New", "Latest"},                       
     {"Sound", "Noise"},                   
     {"Vile", "Base"}};
```

/****Inputing The User***/

```
     string key = ""; 
     Boolean search=true;
     Console.Write("Input Word: ");
     key= Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine();    

     for(int ctr=0; ctr < Words.GetLength(0); ctr++)
```

/****Search if the Value of Key that has been Put the User is true***/

```
         if(key == Words[ctr,0])         
            search=true;
             break;          
         else      
             search=false
     if(search==true)
```

/***How to Get the Value of Words in Second Row****/

```
         Console.WriteLine(Words: " + key+ "Meaning: " +???;
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Found" + key);
```

Please help me..  To create this code of How to get the meaning of the Words: Absolute, Custom, Design, New, Sound, Vile.

Comment: Keep track of the index where you found the matching word (`ctr`) and use it to get the second word.

Comment: Can you please show me the correct code.. Thanks

Comment: What is problem you are facing in your code..? is `"Absolute", "Custom", "Design", "New", "Sound", "Vile"` is all are unique values..

Comment: @RowellUlepTaguba, are you ther, if you could answer my first comment, I can help you out..

Comment: Can you show how the Dictionary is declared in your code, the first line you have shown does not compile.

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar Yes sir it is all unique values

Comment: @iakobski  string[,] Words = new string [,]
         {{"Absolute","Complete"},
         {"Custom","Tradition"},
         {"Design","Plan"},
         {"New", "Latest"},
         {"Sound", "Noise"},
         {"Vile", "Base"}};

Comment: @RowellUlepTaguba, kindly check my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all unqiue keys at first place of every record, then this is right time to use [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Here is the implementation

```
  Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dict.Add("Absolute", "Complete");
  dict.Add("Custom", "Tradition");
  dict.Add("Design", "Plan");
  dict.Add("New", "Latest");
  dict.Add("Sound", "Noise");
  dict.Add("Vile", "Base");
```

Now you can read `Key` of dictionary from user

```
 Console.Write("Input Word: ");
 string key= Console.ReadLine();
```

Now check user input i.e. `key` is available in dictionary or not, like

```
if(dict.ContainsKey(key)) //ContainsKey return true if string i.e. key available in dictionary.
    Console.WriteLine("Word is :" + key + "Meaning is" + dict[key]);
else 
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found" + key);
```